# How to remove parent slugs from child pages permalinks in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I remove them all right, but when I actually try to go to a page, there is a 404 error.

The code I have used ( variation of https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/182006/removing-parent-pages-from-permalink#answer-313280 )

```
function my_pages_permalink( $link, $post_id) {
    $slugname = get_post_field( 'post_name', $post_id, 'display' );
    $slugname = $slugname."/";
    $link = untrailingslashit( home_url($slugname) ) . '.html';
    return $link;
}
add_filter( 'page_link', 'my_pages_permalink', 10, 3 );
```

What else should be done? Some add_rewrite_rule? What it may be like?

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to add `.html` at the end but WordPress pages are dynamic and most of the time `.php` pages.

Also, you are using `untrailingslashit` but then adding the slash back in.
The updated version below checks if the page has a parent. If it does, it constructs the permalink using the child page's slug without including the parent slug. If the page doesn't have a parent, the original permalink is returned.

```
function my_pages_permalink( $link, $post_id ) {
    $post = get_post( $post_id );

    if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_parent ) {
        $parent = get_post( $post->post_parent );
        $link = trailingslashit( home_url() ) . $post->post_name . '.html';
    }

    return $link;
}
add_filter( 'page_link', 'my_pages_permalink', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: You function does remove slugs from child pages, but there it is again: when you click them, you don't go to the expected pages, but end up by 404 error. Also it doesn't add .html extension to topmost parents - not the big deal by now.

So the problem seems to be like WordPress is not aware that a new permalink structure is set. So one has to tell it. I have tried a rewrite rule:

function my_pages_permalink_rewrite() { add_rewrite_rule('^(.+?)/(.+?)$', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[2]', 'top'); } add_action('init', 'my_pages_permalink_rewrite');

but to no avail.

Comment: As to .html or not, it is the easiest part. Adding .html or another extension or not adding at all just works with no problem. The problem is the slug removing. The reason I add .html extension is simple - the owners of the web-site want to have it like this. Since it's not harmful, I am not expected to object.